# how can I access data from array inside array

Tags: react-native

I need to access an image inside 2 arrays, but I have an error to do a map inside another one any suggestions?
all data printed successfully but I need to access an image which is an array inside another array
I need to access an image inside 2 arrays, but I have an error to do a map inside another one any suggestions?

here is the code
`

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Image,Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Artist from '../components/Artist'
import SearchHeader from '../components/SearchHeader';
import { useNavigation, useRoute } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Artistfu } from '../services.js/services';


const ArtistSearch = () => {
  const route = useRoute()
  let token = route.params.token
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const [artistt, setArtistt] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [images, setImages] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    Artistfu().then(artists => {
      setArtistt(artists)
      setImages(artists[0].images)
    }).catch(err => {
      setError(err);
    });
  }, []);
  console.log(artistt)
  return (
    <View>
      {
        artistt.map((ar, i) => (
          <View
            key={i}
          >
            <Text>{ar.followers.total}</Text>
            {images.map((img)=>(
                <Image source={{ uri: img.images.url }} style={{ height: 210, width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 40, resizeMode: 'cover' }} />
            ))}
            <Text >{ar.name}</Text>
            <Text>{ar.popularity}</Text>
          </View>
        ))
      }
    </View>
  )
}

export default ArtistSearch

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
})
```

`services file :`

```
import axios from 'axios';
const apiUrl = 'https://api.spotify.com'
const token = 'query=remaster%2520track%3ADoxy%2520artist%3AMiles%2520Davis&type=artist&market=ES&locale=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.9&offset=5&limit=10'
export const Artistfu = async () => {
    const resp = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}/v1/search?${token}`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
      },
    })
    return resp.data.artists.items
  };
```

`

and the data look like json:
`

```
{
  "artists": {
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=remaster%2520track%3ADoxy%2520artist%3AMiles%2520Davis&type=artist&market=ES&locale=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.9&offset=5&limit=10",
    "items": [
      {
        "external_urls": {
          "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/1MVFEpYdHtdV3k8Bgs79Pl"
        },
        "followers": {
          "href": null,
          "total": 404
        },
        "genres": [],
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1MVFEpYdHtdV3k8Bgs79Pl",
        "id": "1MVFEpYdHtdV3k8Bgs79Pl",
        "images": [
          {
            "height": 640,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000e5ebd1578a57ff89ac9aeed23863",
            "width": 640
          },
          {
            "height": 320,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616100005174d1578a57ff89ac9aeed23863",
            "width": 320
          },
          {
            "height": 160,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000f178d1578a57ff89ac9aeed23863",
            "width": 160
          }
        ],
        "name": "DOXY",
        "popularity": 14,
        "type": "artist",
        "uri": "spotify:artist:1MVFEpYdHtdV3k8Bgs79Pl"
      },
]
}
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The below should work

```
artists.items[0].images
```